# Move folders from Windows 7 to Linux NAS via SSH

Tags: windows-7, linux, ssh, putty, nas

I have many files I want to copy to my NAS device, however, the NAS OS doesn't allow for easy upload of an entire folder. The NAS device I am using is a Thecus N5810pro running the standard Thecus OS included. My first thought was using an SSH connection and to use `scp` command through PuTTY but when I try that the terminal returns

> scp: command not found

Any ideas on how to accomplish this, or is there a better way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like, you can still use SCP on Windows.  Just install [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php).  You can probably use the same credentials you used to SSH within SCP to connect to your NAS.

Additionally, you mentioned that you got a "not found" error.  That's, of course, because it isn't installed on the machine you SSH'ed into.  That's ok though because you need it on the SOURCE machine and not the DEST machine.  Installing WinSCP on your Windows 7 machine should allow you to drag-and-drop folders at will.  Good luck!

Comment: If there's no `scp` on the server, WinSCP won't work. You need `scp` on both sides. That's how SCP protocol works. WinSCP replaces the local machine `scp` only.

Comment: +1; Was typing up pretty much this exact answer.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I'm not entirely sure that's true.  SCP uses SSH keys to negotiate a secure "tunnel" with the endpoint.  So, 'ssh' is the requirement (which we know the user has because he SSH'ed successfully), not 'scp'.

Comment: Brilliant! WinSCP worked and using it didn't even cross my mind. Thanks!

Comment: @jkovba I'm pretty sure, that's true. After all I've implemented the WinSCP, so I know how it works.

Comment: @Daz What protocol did WinSCP ended up using? What do you see on the right side of its status bar?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl WinSCP gave me a list of options and I opted for SCP.

Comment: @Daz That's not what I've asked for. I've asked: *What protocol did WinSCP ended up using? What do you see on the right side of its status bar?*

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Sorry I'm still not entirely sure what you mean. The selected file protocol for the session is SCP. How do I go about viewing this status bar you speak of?

Comment: @Daz What do you see here? https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrgfK.png

Comment: @MartinPrikryl SCP.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Ah, as I said "I'm not entirely" sure so I'll defer to you.  Having read the SCP protocol documentation it does look like the remote end is asked to start an 'scp' process.

Comment: @Daz And did you actually try to transfer some files? Because then it does not make sense that you get "scp: command not found" in the terminal.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I agree with you on this point.  Maybe the command was slightly mistyped or the path to the scp binary is misconfigured?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl This is what my WinSCP looks like, after going on my NAS I can confirm that the file "local-file" was copied over onto the device itself. https://i.gyazo.com/ab1de10bd5e3253161c6d3c56a235109.png

Comment: @Daz Well, I'm glad that you have resolved your problem. But there's something wrong about your question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Oh dear, I think I realise what I did wrong. I've noticed that a few commands don't work on my NAS device, there are for example no man pages which is a bit difficult for a beginner like myself. Before I asked this question I was trying to use the SCP command to grab a file and put it on my laptop but I originally did it FROM the SSH connection. I figured out my error within 2 minutes and correctly grabbed the file, but I guess I just forgot about that and made the assumption that SCP through PuTTY wouldn't work! Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try SFTP or FTP.

---

Or pack your files to an archive (e.g. tar), upload the archive and unpack it on the server.